# Find the cardinal of a specific set>

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

Suppose that $n$ is a fixed integer different from zero,
$D$ is the set of divisors of $n$;
$D=\{1,d_1,...,n\}.$
For every $d_i$ belongs to D, We introduce the set:
$S^n(d_i)=\{1 \leq s \leq n; gcd(s,n)=d_i\}.$

The question is:

> Is there any formula to find the cardinal of $S(d_i)$?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math.SE. Your question looks like homework. Please edit your post to include your attempt(s) at solving the problem as asking for complete solutions to homework is discouraged.

Comment: Hi Watercrystal, I have prepared a Mathematica algorithm to solve this question,I don't want you to do my homework, if you know that there is an old solution for this question plz send me. thank you